# in Godot how do I run logic on the GL texture ID of each rendered frame?

Tags: opengl, gstreamer, godot, gdscript

I am experimenting with Godot 4.1.

I need to route every rendered frame into a gstreamer pipeline.

My first instinct is to get the GL texture handle and target and use them to construct a GstGLBuffer which I can then feed to the pipeline.

I can create a gdscript that extends Node and `var tex = get_viewport().get_texture()` and check its width and height.  But if I call `RenderingServer.texture_get_native_handcle(tex,true)` it always gives me 0 .  I try this code from the `_process()` callback, and I also tried a loop from `_ready()` that does `await RenderingServer.frame_post_draw` followed by the exploration logic.

Is there an example of how to feed rendered frames into gstreamer, or at least how to get the GL handle and render target (TARGET_2D or the OES wackiness) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewportTexture` is not a real texture. It's a proxy texture. The `RID` of the `ViewportTexture` is actually a placeholder texture resource id.

To get the native handle of the last rendered frame texture use the following code:

```gdscript
var rid = RenderingServer.viewport_get_texture(get_viewport().get_viewport_rid())
var handle = RenderingServer.texture_get_native_handle(tex_rid)
```

Comment: That gives me 19, which is an improvement.  What is still lacking is information about how to ensure that the code is run each frame and the texture is valid, and avoid race conditions where the game engine overwrites the pixels before I can encode them.

Comment: the `texture_get_native_handle()` function works.  I am able to fetch the pixels and dump them to a PNG.  Routing them into the nvidia H.265 gstreamer element is proving harder, because the on-GPU color format of the texture is not yet known to me.

Comment: Lacking the ability to figure out the on-GPU format of Godot's rendered texture, we worked around the problem by using the Godot texture in a shader to render into the texture of the Gstreamer GL Buffer, which we can control the format of.